# How to handle google play app with CI build and RC Build

Tags: android, google-play

I have one android app (e.g MyApp) in the Google Play Store, and at the moment the package is from the RC build in our pipeline, but we also want to publish package from CI build for testers. Is it better to create a new app called MyAppTest in play store which receives the package from CI build? Or is it better to just upload the package from CI build to "MyApp" under internal testing track? In the package from RC build, the version is like 1.0.0-RC1, and the package from CI build the version is like 1.1.0.1.

What is the best practice for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep all into a single project! And use the different levels of testing of google play (alpha, closed beta, open beta).

Usually there are some levels of testing:

- Internal testing (Release Candidates)
- Open Beta for selected users

You should try to scale the same version from internal, to open beta to production. Most versions will be transitory, and won't reach production at all.

But you should keep the semantic versions all the way, some devs like to add -RC or -beta after the version to name, to tag as "in testing" version.